# Easiest native implementation or equivalent to std::function for use in callback function

Tags: c++, lambda, callback

I am implementing a callback method inside of a class, the currently working implementation uses `std::function`, however, the STL is not available in the environment I am using. I am seeking to understand how a native implementation would achieve the same result. I have tried using function pointers, this does not work for lambda expression callbacks.

Here is a working example of what I am trying to achieve, using `std::function`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass(std::function<void(void)> callback): _callback(callback) {}
        void call() {
            _callback();
        }
    private:
        std::function<void(void)> _callback;
};

class MyOtherClass {
    public:
        MyOtherClass() {}
        MyClass mc = MyClass([this]() { myInt++; });
        void callFiveTimes() {
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                mc.call();
            }
        }
        void printInt() {
            cout << myInt << endl;
        }
    private:
        int myInt = 0;

};


int main()
{
    MyOtherClass moc = MyOtherClass();
    moc.printInt();
    moc.callFiveTimes();
    moc.printInt();
    return 0;
}
```

So, the question is how can I replace `std::function<void(void)> callback` such that the program will compile without external libraries.

Update:

Here is an example that requires a bit more work, but achieves the result I am after. I would like to be able to just pass in the callback as the parameter rather than the callback, and callback args param.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass(void(*callback)(void*), void* callback_arg): _callback(callback), _callback_arg(callback_arg) {}
        void call() {
            _callback(_callback_arg);
        }
    private:
        void (*_callback)(void*);
        void* _callback_arg;
};

class MyOtherClass {
    public:
        MyClass* mc;
        MyOtherClass() {
            auto callback=[this](){ myInt++; };
            mc = new MyClass([](void* arg){ (*static_cast<decltype(callback)*>(arg))(); },&callback);
        }
        void callFiveTimes() {
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                mc->call();
            }
        }
        void printInt() {
            cout << myInt << endl;
        }
    private:
        int myInt = 0;

};


int main()
{
    MyOtherClass moc = MyOtherClass();
    moc.printInt();
    moc.callFiveTimes();
    moc.printInt();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It already compiles without external libraries.  You can replace it by removing the `void` inside the parentheses.

Comment: If you can't use function pointers, then you will need to "reinvent" `std::function`. So why do this instead of adding original `std::function` (its template, so probably library is not necessary, only header file) from compiler's STL without using complete STL?

Comment: @L.F. no, it doesn't compile without using the STL... this does not answer the question.

Comment: @sklott can you provide an example of how to 'reinvent' the function type?

Comment: @Nathan STL is not an external library. The standard library is a part of C++.  If you want to slow down your development process and insist on reinventing it, you can take a look at [my attempt](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/221921) on Code Review.  Do note that it doesn't implement the mandatory small object optimization, if you are assessing its conformance to the standard.

Comment: @L.F. I have quite clearly stated that the STL is not available within the constraints of the environment I am working with - this is not about insisting on reinventing. The question is about a suitable type replacement for std::function, and how that would be achieved natively, if possible.

Comment: @Nathan Well, you still have to reinvent std::function anyway, if you really want to use std::function without using std::function.  I guess you can simplify by omitting some functionalities if you don't need them in your program, but you can't really sidestep the fundamental idea if you need type erasure.

Comment: @Nathan Do you have access to memory allocation or not?

Comment: @JeffGarrett yes, memory allocation is available.